# How does gclid run with Joomla

Tags: javascript, html, joomla, joomla2.5

I have been following the steps for Tracking offline conversions from Google. I want to be able to set a cookie - read the cookie, set it to a hidden field in my form and then have the form email it.

Here is the code that Google gives:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function setCookie(a,d,b){var c=new Date;c.setTime(c.getTime()+864E5*b);b="; expires="+c.toGMTString();document.cookie=a+"="+d+b}function getParam(a){return(a=RegExp("[?&]"+a+"=([^&]*)").exec(window.location.search))&&decodeURIComponent(a[1].replace(/\+/g," "))}var gclid=getParam("gclid");if(gclid){var gclsrc=getParam("gclsrc");(!gclsrc||-1!==gclsrc.indexOf("aw"))&&setCookie("gclid",gclid,90)};

</script> 

<script> 
  function readCookie(name) { 
  var n = name + "="; 
  var cookie = document.cookie.split(';'); 
  for(var i=0;i < cookie.length;i++) {      
      var c = cookie[i];      
      while (c.charAt(0)==' '){c = c.substring(1,c.length);}      
      if (c.indexOf(n) == 0){return 
  c.substring(n.length,c.length);} 
  } 
  return null; 
  } 

  window.onload = function() {      
      document.getElementById('gclid').value = 
  readCookie('gclid'); 
  } 
  </script>

 <form action="" name="myForm">         
         Name: <input type="text" name="name">      
         <input type="hidden" id="gclid" name="gclid" value="">         
         <input type="submit" value="Submit Form" name="btnSubmit">     
   </form>
```

Both JS's are in the template of Joomla 2.5 and the form is just in an article. 
When I hit submit it sends the email and the "gclid" comes back as undefined.

Is it not setting the cookie - reading the cookie? Do I have to call "setcookie" somewhere in my template for it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to add:

```
<input type="hidden" id="google_code" name="google_code" value="<?php echo $_GET['gclid'];?>">
```

into your form. The above code in my first post wasn't doing anything for it.